# Laravel 5.7 9 Yajra Datatable delete button

Tags: ajax, laravel

My button in the table is created by:

```
return Datatables::of($members)
            ->addColumn('action', function ($id) {
                return '<a href="member/' . $id->id . '/edit" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-delete" data-remote="/admin/members/' . $id->id . '">Delete</button>
                  '; })->make(true);
```

The **js function**:

```
$('#datatable-member').on('click', '.btn-delete[data-remote]', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
        var url = $(this).data('remote');
        alert(url);
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'DELETE',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {method: '_DELETE', submit: true}
        }).always(function (data) {
            $('#datatable-member').DataTable().draw(false);
        });
    });
```

the return of the debugging alert is (for example):  /admin/members/2

The route is this one:

```
DELETE    | admin/members/{member}      | members.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\MemberController@destroy | web
```

I have this error in the *JS console*:

```
jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2 DELETE http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/members/2 404 (Not Found)
```

...and of course, the delete doesn't work...

Comment: change your route to "POST" and try. Share the results.

Comment: If it needed `POST` it'd show a 405 so `DELETE` is probably correct. Check the route exists and that the model exists and that the route binding is set up in the controller action.